# -1 returns second to last item in python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, urllib

I am using Python 3.4 to write a script that pull data from [Yahoo Finance's ChartAPI page](http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/GOOG/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv) by using urllib to pull the data and store it in a text file and numpy to unpack it. However, when ever I try to access the last element in a list by using [-1] I end up with the second to last element instead of the last element.

Here is my relevant code:

```
import urllib.request
import numpy as np

def n_year_data(symbol):
    tempFile = 'temp.txt'
    open(tempFile,'w+') # to clear any previous content

    yahooChartApi = 'http://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/'+symbol+'/chartdata;type=quote;range=1y/csv'
    with urllib.request.urlopen(yahooChartApi) as f:
        sourceCode = f.read().decode('utf-8')
    splitSource = sourceCode.split('\n')

    for eachLine in splitSource:
        splitLine = eachLine.split(',') 
        if len(splitLine) == 6: 
            if 'values' not in eachLine:
                saveFile = open(tempFile,'a')
                linetoWrite = eachLine+'\n'
                saveFile.write(linetoWrite)

    date, close, high, low, openPrice, volume = np.loadtxt(tempFile, delimiter=',', unpack=True)

    print(date[-1])

n_year_data("GOOG")
```

The code above should return the last date, 20150707. However it returns 20150706 the date before the last date. Furthermore when I look at my text file, all the dates are there and as they should be. Thanks in advance for help, or advice.

Comment: Use `print(date)` before `print(date[-1])` to see if 20150707 is the last element.

Comment: I just tried that and no 20150707  isn't that last element, which would explain why it isn't returning it as the last element, but I'm not sure why it isn't being append it to the list even tough it is in the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since **you are not correctly closing the file** after you finish writing, you might end up with having this problem, or other potential problems.

**Don't open and append to the file in the loop.**

Consider using this, instead:

```
with open('temp.txt', 'w') as f:
   for item in iterable:
       f.write('hello')

with open('temp.txt', 'r') as f:
   for line in f:
       print(line)
```